# How to set a timestamp in Django when the class's attribute is set or changed

Tags: python, django

I have a following (simplified) class in `models.py`:

```
class Order( models.Model ) :
    status       = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    t_status     = models.DateTimeField( null = True, blank = True )
    user_status  = models.ForeignKey( User, null = True, blank = True )
    t_created    = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )
    t_modified   = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True )
```

How do I set `t_status` to be a timestamp (much like `t_modified`) when the value of `t_status` changes? Note that `t_status` can be blank. `t_status` would normally changed from NULL to the string `approved` or `rejected`. `user_status` is the person that approves or rejects this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields).

```
class Order(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    ...

def order_pre_save(sender, instance):
    if "status" in instance.get_dirty_fields():
        instance.t_status = datetime.datetime.now()

pre_save.connect(order_pre_save, sender=Order)
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'll check it out. Thanks!